# Inconsistent sizeof Behavior:

Tags: c, output, logic, sizeof

This is the problem of strings chapter from *Let Us C* book ?

```
printf("Size of char = %d\n", sizeof(char));
printf("\n%d %d %d", sizeof('3'), sizeof("3"), sizeof(3));
```

I get this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYsUo.png):

```
Size of char = 1

4 2 4
```

I can't understand why the compiler is showing `4 2 4` output while the size of char is `1` in 64-bit C-compiler so according to my logic it should be `1 2 4`. Can anyone have a look?

Comment: That code will not build, as the single quotes are wrong. Please create a proper [mre], and [edit] your question to copy-paste it into the question.

Comment: Also note that the result of the `sizeof` operator have the type `size_t`, and the correct `printf` format to print such values is `%zu`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Lastly, please make it a habit of printing *trailing* newlines. When connected to a terminal, the newline flushes the output. If you print a leading newline then you write the *previous* line, not the current one. And the last line of output can become mixed with the shell or terminal prompt.

Comment: The image doesn't add anything so I suggest you eliminate it and copy the text here.

Comment: I have updated the question ? Now can anyone look through and help me ?

Answer (score 4):

- `char` by definition is of size 1.
- `'3'` is an integer character constant which is of type `int`.  `sizeof(int) == 4` on your system.
- `"3"` (`{'3', '\0'}`) is a `char [2]`.  Each `char` is `1`.
- `3` is also an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

In C, `'3'` is an *integer character constant*.

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed in single-quotes, as in `'x'`.  C11dr §6.4.4.4 2

`'3'` has type `int`.

> An integer character constant has type `int`. §6.4.4.4 10

---

OP has "... so accordig to my logic it should be 1 ...:

Expecting size 1 is not supported by the C spec.
`'3'` has the size of an `int`.  On OP's platform, that is 4.

---

[Edit]

OP added `printf("Size of char = %d\n" , sizeof(char) ) ;`.

`sizeof(char)` is not relevant to the question as in C, `'3'` is an `int`, not a `char`.

---

This may differ in other languages.
E.g. In C++, `'3'` is a `char` and `char` have size 1.